# Display the highest value in a same column in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to show the highest values in column B which is related to each uniqe reference.I've tried this formula but didn't work.

[The Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkjHj.png)

[Output 01.03.2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90RIe.png)

[This is out put from the below formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrUPS.jpg)

> Blockquote
>   [01.03.2019_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27YUw.jpg)
>   Blockquote

[enter[01.03.2019_2][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMppV.jpg) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9ZxC.jpg)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBhiv.jpg)

whileprintingrecords;
stringvar dept;
if {baseevent1.Column B} = Maximum({baseevent1.Column B},{baseevent1.Referance}) then
dept:={baseevent1.Referance}

Comment: Should the output only show 1 record for each unique value of the Referance column with the max value of Column B and the value of the Formula column that corresponds to the max value of Column?

Comment: Also, if my first question is correct about how you want the output to look, are the values of Column B always unique for each value of Referance?  If they are not, then its possible that there could be two or more records with the same max value and different values for Formula.

Comment: @R.McMillan Thanks for your reply. Yes, that's right, I uploaded the screenshot of the expected output. The values of the column B are not unique, but it's just display the last event of the column B.

Comment: Where did you write the supress formula?

Comment: I’ve tried on both on details section and then column B. But now I used it in the formula

Comment: Supress is always true or flase looks like you didnt write for supress instead you have wrote to display. So write true or false

Comment: @Siva I did try it with true and false in suppress but the thing its jumps to previous maximum values which is not correct

Comment: @Rumi what do you mean by previous maximum values?

Comment: @Siva I mean if the max values of the ABC222 is 14 when I’ve used the suppress is jumping to 13. Which is not correct.

Comment: ok post your supress formula, looks like their is some problem in that formula

Comment: @Siva whileprintingrecords; stringvar dept; if {baseevent1.Column B} = Maximum({baseevent1.Column B},{baseevent1.Referance}) then true else false

Comment: @Rumi change it as `whileprintingrecords; stringvar dept; if {baseevent1.Column B} = Maximum({baseevent1.Column B},{baseevent1.Referance}) then false else true`

Comment: @Siva It is a bit weird, I've placed the formula into Detail section without ticking suppress formula and is working! But now I'm trying to not display pay from another field and when I trying to use Expert Record to filter the Status_ev its jump to the previous status.I uploaded the screenshot.

Comment: @Siva I mean requirements is to not shows the pay into this report.Do you think is to do with Evaluation Time function?

Comment: @Siva I think I've solved the issue by a combination of the formula and using the expert group

Comment: @Rumi great, so now report is completed or any issues still pending?

Comment: @Siva Yes finally is done! That was one of the challenging reporters I've ever done.It's required very good understanding of SQL and hierarchical database. Any way, I've learned a lot and thanks for chasing this up.

Comment: @Rumi No Problem, add your answer, accept it and close the thread, so that others can use

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to achieve your goal with less formula usage and more grouping and sorting.

You will need 2 grouping levels.  The top-most group will be Referance, and then below that group on Column B.  Ensure that Column B is sorted from lowest to highest.  By sorting this way, the very last detail record will always contain the highest value of Column B.

Then suppress both group header section, suppress the details section, and suppress the Column B group footer section.

Place data fields for Referance, Column B, and Formula in the Referance Group Footer Section.

By grouping and sorting in this manner, when you reach the footer section for your top most grouping, the values each field contains will always be the record that had the maximum value of Column B.

No need for any formula fields at all with this approach.  :)

Just do be aware, that if you ever have a duplicate value in Column B within a Referance Group, then you are going to run into issues, as this approach will print only the values of the last record in the grouped data.  However, even with a formulaic approach like you began with, you were still going to run into this issue should there be any duplicates in the composite key value created by concatenating Referance and Column B.

Comment: I've tried your solution but for some reason didn't work it may be to do with duplication of values. Then end up with using formula +  expert group and now is working.Thanks anyway thanks for your time